# How to clear a PHP session using Jquery/Javascript?

Tags: php, jquery, session

Just want to ask if is it possible to clear a PHP session using a jquery or javascript process? Because what I want to do is to clear the PHP session using a dialog box. If the user click the 'OK' button it will process the unset function. In my page there's a checkout process and after the user click the button 'OK' it will prompt a dialog box and if the user click the 'OK' button it will unset the PHP session and it will be redirected to another page.

Here's my simple code:

```
<i class="fa fa-check"></i> <span id="save_registry" class="cursor: pointer">OK</span>

<div id="save_alert" style="display: none">
    <?php unset($this->session->data['cart']);
</div>


....

$('#save_registry').click(function(){

        $('#save_alert').dialog({
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                Ok: function() {
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                    location = 'index.php?route=common/home'; 
                }
            }
        });

});
```

Comment: You could delete the session cookie. However, to properly log out you'd need to make an ajax call so your PHP script could clear the `$_SESSION` variable and properly expire the cookie to prevent session hijacking.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Simply put: You can't, *directly*.

PHP is a **server-side** language while javascript is a **client-side** one, which means that there's no other connection between them other than the document you receive and interacts with you. The sessions are stored and managed by the **server**.

You can, however, as War10ck suggests, call to a server-side script that clears the session. Something like this:

PHP:

```
<?php
    /* 
     * session_start();
     * Starting a new session before clearing it
     * assures you all $_SESSION vars are cleared 
     * correctly, but it's not strictly necessary.
     */
    session_destroy();
    session_unset();
    header('Location: continue.php'); 
    /* Or whatever document you want to show afterwards */
?>
```

HTML/javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function logout() {
        document.location = 'logout.php';
    }
    LogoutButton.addEventListener('click', logout, false);
</script>

<button id="LogoutButton">Log out</button>
```

Or even performing an asynchronous call:

```
function logout() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onload = function() {
        document.location = 'continue.php';
    }
    xhr.open('GET', 'logout.php', true);
    xhr.send();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It really helps me in understanding session. :) I will try your suggestions. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Worked for me ! Thank you

Answer (score 5):

There is a way you can do it directly from javascript... first you have to declare a function that clears a cookie by its key

```
function removeCookie(cookieName)
{
    cookieValue = "";
    cookieLifetime = -1;
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime()+(cookieLifetime*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    document.cookie = cookieName+"="+JSON.stringify(cookieValue)+expires+"; path=/";
}
```

Now all you have to do is to remove a cookie with the key "`PHPSESSID`" like this

```
removeCookie("PHPSESSID");
```

Now when you `var_dump($_SESSION)` you find it empty array

Comment: Note that javascript is not **directly** removing the session: the client reads the cookie, invalidates it and sends the proper information to the server, which then expires the session accordingly. +1 for the alternative solution.

Answer (score 3):

You can't clear a php session using Javascript directly.

PHP is a server-side language, whereas Javascript is client-side..

However, you can throw an ajax request to the specified page that handles the destruction.

Like this:

```
// Client-side
$.post("logout.php", {"can_logout" : true}, function(data){

   if(data.can_logout)
      // redirect the user somewhere
}, "json");


<?php
   // Server-side
   $can_logout = $_POST["can_logout"];

   if($can_logout)
     session_destroy();

   echo json_encode(array("can_logout" => true));
?>
```

Or just point the user to some page that handles the session destruction; i.e. `logout.php`